# regex: required character in brackets

Tags: regex

How do I search for a string that contains only chars from a set including `x`, and require it to contain x? e.g. `[a-z]+` but not matching if it doesn't contain `x`.

So it should match `quux` but not `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: your question is contradictory, you say only characters `x, y and/or z` and then go on to say `a-z` and that `quux` should match.

Comment: That's not what I meant by "x, y, and/or z" but I edited it to clarify.

Comment: so you really only want it to match "x." Because by your logic, `yyz` won't match, but `abx` will match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to match a string of only x,y or z, match start (`^`) followed by zero or more `y` or `z` (`[yz]*`) followed by an `x` followed by zero or more `x`, `y` or `z` (`[xyz]*`) followed by end (`$`)

```
^[yz]*x[xyz]*$
```

If you are trying to match `[a-z]` but with an `x` in there somewhere, then this should do it

```
^[a-z]*x[a-z]*$
```

Answer (score 5):

try something like this

`^[a-z]*x[a-z]*$`

Comment: `x` is not needed in first character class

Comment: it's not needed, but it's not hurting anything. If it's in a really critical block of code that needs to be optimized, it will eliminate the need to backtrace, but I don't think it's that important.

Comment: this will match `123@xyz.com` you should have the start and end delimiters in there

Answer (score 3):

`[a-z]*x[a-z]*` should do the trick.

Comment: that expression doesn't match, he asked for a regex that will match ONLY chars x, y, and/or z (i.e not a, b, c, ...)

Comment: The answer is fine; by 'x, y, and/or z' I meant any set of characters which is why I didn't write '`x`, `y`, and/or `z`'.