# Regex - How to write a regex to only capture numbers or alphanumeric but not only letters

Tags: regex

I am working for something and writing a regular expression to capture a string which is either (numbers and letters) or only numbers. 
I know a regex for only number is `[0-9]` and alphanumeric is `[A-Za-z0-9]` . But this would capture even the strings which are only letters. How do i force it to not have only letters? Is there a way to do it in a single regex?

Comment: I guess this is pretty similar to what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831611/regex-required-character-in-brackets

Comment: yes. thank you @montonero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])+([a-zA-Z]*)
```

This should solve your problem.

You can test it [here](https://regexr.com/46plp)

Comment: This could maybe simplified to something like [`/[a-z\d]*\d[a-z]*/i`](https://regex101.com/r/SV31WO/1)